# r.js-optimising a directory but skipping included/concatenated files

Tags: javascript, requirejs, r.js

I have a nice setup of require.js + r.js. Right now, i seem to have a "one or the other" choice between these two:

- Use *name* + *out* options to just create one js-file, nothing else
- Use *appDir* + *dir* options which will copy over ALL the files from appDir to dir

The second option is what i am currently using. This will, howeever, copy and minify a lot of files that are actually included in my compiled main.js. Those files will never actually be loaded.

Does r.js have some option to just skip over files that are part of the minification-process?

**An Illustratrion**

Let's pretend I have these files in `appDir`:

```
index.html
main.js
lib/
  - libA.js (dependency of main, will be loaded by require.js)
  - libB.js (dependency of main, will be loaded by require.js)
  - libC.js (loaded any other way)
img/
  - imgA.png
  - imgB.png
```

The first option (name+out) will just yield a huge uglified `main.js`.

```
main.js
```

The second option (appDir+dir) will create something like this in `dir/`

```
index.html
main.js (uglified)
lib/
  - libA.js (uglified and will never be loaded)
  - libB.js (uglified and will never be loaded)
  - libC.js (uglified and used)
img/
  - imgA.png
  - imgB.png
```

What i would ACTUALLY like is this:

```
index.html
main.js
lib/
  - libC.js (no libA.js / libB.js)
img/
  - imgA.png
  - imgB.png
```

(so without the libs that are included in main.js anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me `removeCombined` is the option you want. From the file that lists [all options](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js):

```
//If set to true, any files that were combined into a build bundle will be
//removed from the output folder.
removeCombined: false,
```

The `false` value there shows the default.

By the way, it is really worth going through this file and looking at all the options because the [page](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html) that introduces the optimizer is not by any means covering them all. Going through it again recently, I discovered an option that was added in the latest release of RequireJS.

Comment: Thank you very much for that link. I didn't know it existed, but now that i know what i'm looking for, i see that it's actually mentioned in §14 of the [docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#options). A first quick test seems to indicate that this can't be supplied as a command line argument (`r.jd -o removeCombined=true` did not work, but putting it into a build.js _did_ work) Thanks a lot!

Comment: Now it works just as i wanted it:
`node tools/r.js -o name=main removeCombined=true useStrict=true
 appDir="www" dir="www-release" mainConfigFile="../www/main.js"`